# invalid object name #temp between rpc and sp starting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that creates some temporary tables and runs some dynamic sql using them.

I'm creating the temp tables first, then inserting into them, then running the exec(@sql) that references them.

The app I'm building that uses this proc calls it a few times in a row. I traced it, and saw something I don't understand. I'm looking at RPC:Starting, RPC:Completed, SP:Starting, SP:Completed, and Exceptions. The trace looks like this:

```
RPC:Starting    exec my_proc
Exception       Invalid object name '#temp'. --a few of these
SP:Starting     exec my_proc
SP:Completed    exec my_proc
RPC:Completed   exec my_proc
```

Everything works, I'm just confused about what's going on with that exception between the `RPC:Starting` and `SP:Starting`. Could someone please explain? I was under the impression my procedure didn't start until the SP:Starting.

Edit: Timestamps for Exception, SP:Starting, and SP:StmtStarting for `CREATE TABLE #temp1 (test INT)` are all the same. The statement `INSERT INTO #temp1...`, is .003 seconds later.

The simplified version of the whole procedure is:

```
...AS
CREATE TABLE #temp1 
(test INT)

INSERT INTO #temp1
SELECT some_numbers
FROM some_table

--Simplification, but same premise,
--Concatenate a partial statement with result from querying the #temp table
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 
'CREATE VIEW ['+@someName+'] AS SELECT '+SELECT test FROM #temp1+' FROM some_other_table'

DROP TABLE #temp1

BEGIN TRY
    exec(@sql)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Edit 2: Forgot to mention, this error only happens on the FIRST execution of the procedure when it's called a couple times in a row by my app.

Comment: Would be helpful if 1) you tell us whether the timestamps are the same between `sp_starting` and `exception` (I'm guessing they are, and that the `exception` gets blatted out with a higher priority), and 2) the code you're executing, so we have some idea whether there's a problem with the proc or what.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you `DROP TABLE #temp1` too soon. A slightly simplified version of your code that works is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1 
(test INT)

INSERT INTO #temp1
SELECT 1
FROM sometable

--Simplification, but same premise,
--Concatenate a partial statement with result from querying the #temp table
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 
'CREATE VIEW etc AS SELECT test FROM #temp1 '

BEGIN TRY
    exec(@sql)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

select * from #temp1
DROP TABLE #temp1
```

Notice that the view has a name and `DROP TABLE` is moved after `dynamic SQL query` is executed.

Comment: Derped on the view name while typing that part in here, it has a name in the proc. As for the DROP time, I moved it as you suggested, but I'm still seeing the same error.

Comment: It is highly probable that presented code does not grasp the whole flow. You can try the following: `SELECT * from #temp1` before entering BEGIN TRY. Then, print @@ERROR in your CATCH to allow to run from SSMS and see the errors like this (better that in your profiler, since you can put PRINTs and SELECTs to know exactly where it fails).

Comment: I'll give it a go, but the proc doesn't show any errors when I run it in SSMS, only when I run through the app, and only on the first run out of several. And it is completing successfully every run, generating the view as I want. It's just I have no idea where those exceptions are coming from.

Comment: BEGIN CATCH .. END CATCH ensures that no errors will bubble from SQL to your app, that's why putting a print there might help to solve the mystery :).

Answer (score 0):

There's actually nothing wrong with your code, and the error can be ignored.

It's happening because of a SQL Server feature called [Deferred Name Resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190686(v=sql.105)). At the time the batch is compiled, the #temp1 table doesn't exist - Profiler is reporting this. When it comes to actually executing the batch though, the table has been created and hence the stored procedure executes successfully.